# getting redirect to [URL]/robots.txt in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, url, redirect, web-crawler, robots.txt

I don't know what I have installed, if it was maybe installed on its own or what setting I have changed that now (sometimes) when I want to navigate to an specific url (only accesible when I'm connected to my company's network) I get redirected to a file [URL]/robots.txt in google chrome.

I never faced this behavior and none of my colleagues are currently facing it. I wonder if I have changed a setting of if I have installed an extension that does it.

Any hint out there to get rid of this annoying behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling Google Chrome.

And uninstall all extension.

There are some extensions that change the user-agent of the browser and the relevant web page might be not allowing unknown user-agents to visit it.